# LINQ to XML Processing

Tags: linq-to-xml

I have a sample XML documents like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Employees>
 <Employee>
    <EmpId>1</EmpId>
    <Name>Shawn</Name>   
 </Employee>
 <Employee>
    <EmpId>2</EmpId>
    <Name>Neil</Name>
 </Employee>
 <Employee>
    <EmpId>3</EmpId>
    <Name>Kate</Name>
  </Employee>
 <Employee>
    <EmpId>4</EmpId>
    <Name>Robert</Name>
</Employee>
</Employees>
```

I would like to display the employees name.

I am using the following code snippet

```
 XElement doc = XElement.Load("loading document");
 IEnumerable<XElement> employees = doc.Elements();
```

How to extend the code to display employee names?

Comment: Well, what have you tried before asking? (Hint: you probably want to call `Element("Name")` on each `Employee` element...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 XElement doc = XElement.Load("loading document");
 IEnumerable<string> result = doc.Root.Elements().SelectMany(n => n.Elements("Name")).Select(n => n.Value);
```

will get you all the names in an `IEnumerable<string>`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
XElement doc = XElement.Load(@"loading document")
IEnumerable<XElement> employees = doc.Elements();

foreach (var employee in employees )
   {
        Console.WriteLine(employee.Element("Name").Value);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
XElement doc = XElement.Load(@"loading document")   

// Get all employeesNames
IEnumerable<string> employeesNames=
        from el in doc.Root.Descendants("Employee")       
        select el.Descendants("Name");
```